# Create Table from Year "Start" to the "End"

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, text-parsing

I have a list. Mostly obituary related.

```
Leonard Wilson 1867 - 1936
Mark Jonson 1892 - 1961
Alex Jean Kinshaw 1951 - 1993
Elizabeth Mae Martin 1934 - 1998
```

The data needs to be analysed for a study and it needs to be arranged in 'csv' format, with a timeline(delimited by "," and using "-" for null values) starting from 1850 upto 2015.

```
Leonard Wilson,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,1867,1868,1869......1934,1935,1936,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-
Mark Jonson,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,1892,1893,1894,1895,1896,1897......,1958,1959,1960,1961,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-
....


# All years in the middle needs to be populated please
```

In the above data you can see that the years before the person was born is marked by '-' and also the years after death(till 2015) with the same.   All the years in between, needs to be populated.

The python/pandas code needs to detect the year of start and end, and

1. fill the before null values
2. in-middle years and
3. ending null values

Is there anyway this can be achieved, as I have a data of over 30k rows?

Comment: Try using [fillna()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html#pandas-dataframe-fillna) for filling NA values with your own values and [apply()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html#pandas-dataframe-apply) for converting your timestamp data row by row. Just wanted to know your columns are years right (1850...2015)?

Comment: thank you for responding @k33da_lets_debug, yes please... the columns are for the years (1850...2015)..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep, you can do it like this:

```
df = pd.read_clipboard(header=None, sep='\s\s+')

df_a = df[0].str.rsplit(n=3, expand=True)

df_a = df_a.set_index(0)

full_range = pd.date_range('12/31/1850', '12/31/2015', freq='AS') 
df_a['range'] = [','.join(pd.date_range(i, j, freq='AS')
                            .to_series()
                            .dt.strftime('%Y')
                            .reindex(full_range, fill_value='-')) for i, j in zip(df_a[1], df_a[3])]

df_a.to_csv('test.csv')
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: 30K rows might be a bit expensive on CPU cycles.

Comment: Thank you for the solution Scott.. but I get this error...__ C:\Code_Trials\Trials.py:9: ParserWarning: Falling back to the 'python' engine because the 'c' engine does not support regex separators (separators > 1 char and different from '\s+' are interpreted as regex); you can avoid this warning by specifying engine='python'.
  df = pd.read_csv("names_data.txt", header=None, sep='\s\s+')_________[[also, I am using Python 3.7.8, if it helps]]

Comment: Oh.. you have to figure out a way to read in your dataframe.  I just use pd.read_clipboard because it was easy for me to copy your text from the question.  Those parameters might not make any sense for your data.

Comment: ohh ok :) I am trying to get the data read by pandas, but then not sure how to parse it in a format it can make sense

Comment: If you use  your copy and paste with the text in this question and use pd.read_clipboard, as I have here.  You can print df to see the format I am using to massage your data.  The look at df_a after the split line.

Comment: ok sure, I will try, but I hope it doesnt crash when executing the code .. like you had mentioned earlier that it can be taxing on the machine...

Comment: Thanks Scott, I just tried it on the sample data, and it works as you had shown in the screenshot... however, is there a way to show even the last year, like for example, if it ends in 1961, it should also show 1961, rather than stop in 1960 pls..

Comment: ohh sure, so pls correct me if I am wrong here... I have edited as below, where in the for statement, I have made it j+1 ::: reindex(full_range, fill_value='-')) for i, j+1 in zip(df_a[1], df_a[3])]

Comment: Nah.. let's do this instead change A to AS.  year start for freq in the date_range function.  Does that work better? both freq.. change to AS instead of A.

Comment: sure thing.. I hope I got it right this time... :) :: full_range = pd.date_range('12/31/1850', '12/31/2015', freq='AS')

Comment: also, the second freq in the list comprehension.

Comment: Oh yes, perfect! It worked :) ... Thank you so much for your help Scott... a very Merrry  Christmas to you and family... God Bless You :)

Comment: @Lokkii9 Merry Christmas. Be safe and stay healthy!

Answer (score 2):

Another way, just handle row by row:

```py
import pandas as pd
import io

df_str = '''
dataLeonard Wilson 1867 - 1936
Mark Jonson 1892 - 1961
Alex Jean Kinshaw 1951 - 1993
Elizabeth Mae Martin 1934 - 1998
'''
obj = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(df_str.strip()), 
                 sep='\n', 
                 index_col=False, 
                 header=None)
df = obj[0].str.rsplit(' ', 3, expand=True)
df.columns=['name', 'start_yr', '-', 'end_yr']
print(df)


#                       name start_yr  - end_yr
#     0    dataLeonard Wilson     1867  -   1936
#     1           Mark Jonson     1892  -   1961
#     2     Alex Jean Kinshaw     1951  -   1993
#     3  Elizabeth Mae Martin     1934  -   1998

# conver to int column
df[['start_yr', 'end_yr']] = df[['start_yr', 'end_yr']].astype(int)
# iterrows
# expand the start_year and end_year
dfn_list = list()
for _, row in df.iterrows():
    name = row['name']
    start_yr = row['start_yr']
    end_yr = row['end_yr']  
    dfn = pd.DataFrame(list(range(start_yr, end_yr + 1)), columns=['yr'])
    dfn['name'] = name
    dfn['tag']  = dfn['yr'].astype(str)
    dfn_list.append(dfn)

# merge
dfm = pd.concat(dfn_list)
print(dfm.head())

#         yr                name   tag
#     0  1867  dataLeonard Wilson  1867
#     1  1868  dataLeonard Wilson  1868
#     2  1869  dataLeonard Wilson  1869
#     3  1870  dataLeonard Wilson  1870
#     4  1871  dataLeonard Wilson  1871

# transformat
dfm = dfm.set_index(['name', 'yr'])['tag'].unstack(fill_value='-')
dfm.to_csv('test.csv', header=None)

!cat test.csv
```

result:

```
Alex Jean Kinshaw,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,1951,1952,1953,1954,1955,1956,1957,1958,1959,1960,1961,1962,1963,1964,1965,1966,1967,1968,1969,1970,1971,1972,1973,1974,1975,1976,1977,1978,1979,1980,1981,1982,1983,1984,1985,1986,1987,1988,1989,1990,1991,1992,1993,-,-,-,-,-
Elizabeth Mae Martin,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,1934,1935,1936,1937,1938,1939,1940,1941,1942,1943,1944,1945,1946,1947,1948,1949,1950,1951,1952,1953,1954,1955,1956,1957,1958,1959,1960,1961,1962,1963,1964,1965,1966,1967,1968,1969,1970,1971,1972,1973,1974,1975,1976,1977,1978,1979,1980,1981,1982,1983,1984,1985,1986,1987,1988,1989,1990,1991,1992,1993,1994,1995,1996,1997,1998
Mark Jonson,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,1892,1893,1894,1895,1896,1897,1898,1899,1900,1901,1902,1903,1904,1905,1906,1907,1908,1909,1910,1911,1912,1913,1914,1915,1916,1917,1918,1919,1920,1921,1922,1923,1924,1925,1926,1927,1928,1929,1930,1931,1932,1933,1934,1935,1936,1937,1938,1939,1940,1941,1942,1943,1944,1945,1946,1947,1948,1949,1950,1951,1952,1953,1954,1955,1956,1957,1958,1959,1960,1961,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-
dataLeonard Wilson,1867,1868,1869,1870,1871,1872,1873,1874,1875,1876,1877,1878,1879,1880,1881,1882,1883,1884,1885,1886,1887,1888,1889,1890,1891,1892,1893,1894,1895,1896,1897,1898,1899,1900,1901,1902,1903,1904,1905,1906,1907,1908,1909,1910,1911,1912,1913,1914,1915,1916,1917,1918,1919,1920,1921,1922,1923,1924,1925,1926,1927,1928,1929,1930,1931,1932,1933,1934,1935,1936,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-
```

Comment: thank you for the solution, Ferris.. I will work with this one too :)